# Angular get browser name and version

Tags: javascript, typescript, user-agent

I need to print browser name and version when run it on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. Following code is working on chrome, but not working in IE and Edge. So can someone please explain the below code (what are these characters (?=/))/?\s*(\d+)/i) ,tem ..etc). This code is written by someone else.
Than you

```
getBrowserVersion(){

      var userAgent= navigator.userAgent, tem, 

      matchTest= userAgent.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];

      if(/trident/i.test(matchTest[1])){

          tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(userAgent) || [];

          return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');

      }

      if(matchTest[1]=== 'Chrome'){

          tem= userAgent.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);

          if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');

      }

      matchTest= matchTest[2]? [matchTest[1], matchTest[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];

      if((tem= userAgent.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) matchTest.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);

      return matchTest.join(' ');

}
```

Comment: The characters are creating [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to define a pattern of characters to match in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
const isIEOrEdge = /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
```

i used above please try once

Comment: Thank you. its not working for me. Can you please tell how did you add it ?

Comment: just write above  on component.ts file   in Ngoninit or constructor then console log declared variable i.e. isIEOrEdge

Comment: thank you. seems like this is not working to Angular new version. still it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like "Bowser": https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

```
const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
console.log(browser.getBrowser());

// outputs
{
  name: "Internet Explorer"
  version: "11.0"
}
```

Comment: thank you. how can we add this library to angular? Sorry i am not familiar with git

Comment: You just have to use it like in the documentation.
`npm i bowser` and `import * as Bowser from "bowser";` It's fully compatible with TypeScript and "by definition" with Angular.

Comment: Above works in console. but it shows [object object] in front-end.. how can we get names?